# In Hive, when I load data from csv file, I only get a part of columns, not the whole things

Tags: hive, loading, import-from-csv

Here are the columns in my data source

```
BibNum  
Title   
Author  
ISBN    
PublicationYear 
Publisher   
Subjects    
ItemType    
ItemCollection  
FloatingItem    
ItemLocation    
ReportDate  
ItemCount
```

I got only values by the column of `publisher`.
I uploaded a screenshot , if you know the reason and the way can be fixed, please let me know it will be really appreciated:

[image: Screenshot of messy columns]

Below is the **real** value of the first row ( I separated with // mark to express each column )

```
3011076// 
A tale of two friends / adapted by Ellie O'Ryan ; illustrated by Tom Caulfield, Frederick Gardner, Megan Petasky, and Allen Tam.     // 
O'Ryan, Ellie   // 
1481425730, 1481425749, 9781481425735, 9781481425742    // 
2014    // 
Simon Spotlight,    Musicians Fiction, Bullfighters Fiction, Best friends Fiction, Friendship Fiction, Adventure and adventurers Fiction    // 
jcbk    // 
ncrdr   // 
Floating // 
qna  // 
09/01/2017 //   
1
```

And this is real value of second row

```
2248846 //  
Naruto. Vol. 1, Uzumaki Naruto / story and art by Masashi Kishimoto ; [English adaptation by Jo Duffy]. // 
Kishimoto, Masashi, 1974- //    
1569319006  // 
2003, c1999.    // 
Viz,    Ninja Japan Comic books strips etc, Comic books strips etc Japan Translations into English, Graphic novels //   
acbk//  
nycomic//   
NA//    
lcy//   
09/01/2017//    
1



hive> select * from timesheet limit 3;
OK
NULL    Title   Author  ISBN    PublicationYear Publisher   Subjects    ItemType    ItemCollection  FloatingItem    ItemLocation    ReportDate  ItemCount
3011076 "A tale of two friends / adapted by Ellie O'Ryan ; illustrated by Tom Caulfield Frederick Gardner    Megan Petasky   and Allen Tam."    "O'Ryan  Ellie" "1481425730  1481425749  9781481425735   9781481425742" 2014.   "Simon Spotlight
2248846 "Naruto. Vol. 1  Uzumaki Naruto / story and art by Masashi Kishimoto ; [English adaptation by Jo Duffy]."   "Kishimoto   Masashi     1974-" 1569319006  "2003    c1999."    "Viz    "   "Ninja Japan Comic books strips etc  Comic books strips etc Japan Translations into English
Time taken: 0.149 seconds
hive> desc timesheet
    > ;
OK
bibnum  bigint  
title   string  
author  string  
isbn    string  
publication string  
publisher   string  
subjects    string  
itemtype    string  
itemcollection  string  
floatingitem    string  
itemlocation    string  
reportdate  string  
itemcount   string  
Time taken: 0.21 seconds
```

BibNum,Title,Author,ISBN,PublicationYear,Publisher,Subjects,ItemType,ItemCollection,FloatingItem,ItemLocation,ReportDate,ItemCount | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            |
|

3011076,"A tale of two friends / adapted by Ellie O'Ryan ; illustrated by Tom Caulfield, Frederick Gardner, Megan Petasky, and Allen Tam.","O'Ryan, Ellie","1481425730, 1481425749, 9781481425735, 9781481425742",2014.,"Simon Spotlight,","Musicians Fiction, Bullfighters Fiction, Best friends Fiction, Friendship Fiction, Adventure and adventurers Fiction",jcbk,ncrdr,Floating,qna,09/01/2017,1 | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            | NULL            |

Comment: did you quote all of the commas in your new dataset when importing?

Comment: also how are you importing? It's likely the commas in each column not being escaped

Comment: The way I used is I made table first to use create table table_name(column names data types..) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile; and load data inpath '/path/' into table table_name

Comment: can you upload some of what hive thought the data was, rather than just an image?

Comment: It's probably an issue with the commas note being enclosed in quotes

Comment: You mean the outputs ? I edited with real outputs.

Comment: does that answer help? It's most likely just that `csv` isn't the best format... but it could be something else. In any case, I'm certain it's the data itself so fixing this could be messy

Comment: unless you can get the data as a [parquet](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Parquet) or [Avro](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Apache Hive, by itself can't handle the data like this CSV, but with a [SerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe) (Serializer/Deserializer) it can help with that

with hive v0.14+ the serde is built in and the default separator is `,` so for your CSV this should work

```
create table table_name(column names data types..) 
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
stored as textfile; 
and load data inpath '/path/' 
into table table_name
```

If there are unescaped quotes in any of the columns you will have to manually go in and figure our which columns are which though...

Comment: Cannot validate serde: com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde. I got this error,, Would you know this error?

Comment: did you include the `.jar` file?

Comment: I got a hive-serde-0.10.0-cdh4.2.1.jar
in /usr/lib/hive/lib location

Comment: FAILED: Error in metadata: Cannot validate serde: com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
Error saying like above.

Comment: could you post this in a second question? give it the same tags and I'll look for it

Comment: Okay I can do that.

Comment: Hello, Sir I am using GCP, but I think GCP doesn't support Serde command. Is there any way to use or fix it?

Comment: [dataproc has hive 2](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-versions) so it's built-into hive, see [the csv serde docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde) it's `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde`

Comment: It worked after changing this 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde' comment to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde. Thanks :)

Comment: Sir, all of values are stored only first column, would you know the reason?

Comment: I appended the outputs I got from on GCP to the end of this writing. If you know the reason, please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: and of course, I used the syntax you tole me, like create table table_name(column names data types..) 
row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
 with serdeproperties (
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "'",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
  )
stored as textfile; 
and load data inpath '/path/' 
into table table_name

Answer (score 0):

Since the csv file is delimited by commas, if you specify a column as string entire line will be loaded into that column. So while creating the table you can specify that the row values are delimited by the comma.

```
create table table_name (
....
) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Then load the csv file using

```
load data local inpath path_to_file to table table_name;
```

Hope this helps :)